# Extract URL parameters from URL? In DELPHI

Tags: delphi, url, pascal, lazarus

I have an incoming URL which I need to catch some parameters, our project is in Delphi. Here is what the URL looks like :

I need to get the value right after "state" and before'code'.
I am using a class from System.Net.URLClient.TURI

```
AURL = 'https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/approval/v2?auto=false&response=state%3DF409B222-B0B5-4AF0-B3A2-BC64DCEDA5B6%26code%3D4%2F1AY0e-g6kT90V4_L-HN_BkljW8XCAP79bVIaoE7ZErspKCTr83teAEPxbyHs%26scope%3Dprofile%2520openid%2520https%3A%2F%2Fwww.googleapis.com%2Fauth%2Fuserinfo.profile%26authuser%3D0%26prompt%3Dconsent&approvalCode=4%2F1AY0e-g6kT90V4_L-HN_BkljW8XCAP79bVIaoE7ZErspKCTr83teAEPxbyHs#'
uri := TUri.Create(AUrl); 
returnstate := uri.ParameterByName['state'];
```

When using the parameterbyname it's empty.
Appreciate the help.

Comment: The parameter names in your example are `auto`,`response` and `approvalCode`. There is no `state` parameter, it is part of the `response` parameter's value.

Comment: i know, should i make a loop then? is there a easier way?

Comment: I see after URL decoding the `response` parameter is yet another set of parameters : `state`, `code`, `authuser` and `prompt`.

Comment: how do i access those parameters? i

Comment: @Brian There is also a `scope` parameter, too

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As stated in the comments, you need to decode the `response` parameter.

First step is percent decoding.  You can use `TURLEnconding` for this.

```pascal
Response := TURLEncoding.Decode(uri.ParameterByName['response']);
```

Then, break the embedded `response` at the encoded `&` characters.  There may be an easier way to do it, but you could use `Pos`, or a `TPerlRegEx`.  I think a quick way would be to use a `TStringList` and set the `&` as the `Delimiter` character:

```pascal
ResponseParams := TStringList.Create;
ResponseParams.Delimiter := '&';
ResponseParams.DelimitedText := Response;
```

Then, you have name-value pairs and a standard `TStringList` will separate those for you.

```pascal
ResponseParams.Values['status']
```